# Convert ResultSet into double in a Web Service

Tags: java

I've executed my request and it works and returns the correct result, but I 
I think there's a problem converting the `ResultSet` contents into a `double`.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
public double operation(@WebParam(name = "ncin") int ncin) {
    Double x =0.0;  String _req="";
    _conn = _db.getConnection();

    if(_conn== null)
        System.out.println ("probléme de conn !");

    try {
        _st = _conn.createStatement ();
        _req="SELECT moyenne FROM INES.UNTITLED WHERE (ncin="+ncin+");";
        _rs =_st.executeQuery(_req);  

        if (_rs.next()){
            x =  _rs.getDouble(3);
        }
        System.out.println("la moyenne : "+x);          
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

   return x ;
}
```

I need your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's not written in english.

Comment: Please post your question in English and not in French. Also, could you format it properly? Post your error message also.

Comment: Bonjour je ne speak pas Francaise. Sorry lol

Comment: Please post in English on this site.

Comment: I also do translations from Finnish and in the worst case, Swedish.

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing an SQLException (if `_rs` is a `java.sql.ResultSet`), since you are trying to fetch the 3rd column from the query, which doesn't exist, since all you selected was "moyenne".

To fix this, replace

`x =  _rs.getDouble(3);`

with

`x =  _rs.getDouble(1);`
or
`x =  _rs.getDouble("moyenne");`